# ADS-syntax parser error in `<ADS netlist>', line xx: syntax error

Tags: simulation, schematics, error, ads

I have the problem with ADS when I am simulating my schematic design. Here is the error message:

```
Simulation Messages

Error detected by hpeesofsim during netlist parsing.
    ADS-syntax parser error in `<ADS netlist>', line 46:
        syntax error

Status / Summary


hpeesofsim (*) 490.shp Nov 12 2018, MINT version 4
    (64-bit windows built: Tue Nov 13, 2018 02:20:54 +0000)
--------------------
Simulation terminated due to error.
--------------------
```

In fact, I do not know where is the "ADS netlist" which it refers to. How can I find this in ADS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this problem, you should go to the "Design netlist" file, open it, and find the error in the related line which the error message refers to. In the following link, you can find the complete answer to the problem in ADS or even in any similar software:

[ADS syntax parser error in ADS netlist, line "xx" - ADS error solved](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ujt3JKzivOo)

Answer (score 0):

In the schematic view, click the "Dynamiclink" button, then following click "Top-level Design netlist" button,there are "Design netlist".
In the following, you can find the "xx" line cause the error.